# SQL: How can I count unique instances grouped by client ordered by date?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table in a Snowflake data warehouse:

| Client_ID | Appointment_Date | Store_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client_1 | 1/1/2021 | Store_1 |
| Client_2 | 1/1/2021 | Store_1 |
| Client_1 | 2/1/2021 | Store_2 |
| Client_2 | 2/1/2021 | Store_1 |
| Client_1 | 3/1/2021 | Store_1 |
| Client_2 | 3/1/2021 | Store_1 |

I need to be able to count the number of unique `Store_ID` for each `Client_ID` in order of `Appointment_Date`. Something like following is my desired output:

| Customer_ID | Appointment_Date | Store_ID | Count_Different_Stores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client_1 | 1/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |
| Client_2 | 1/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |
| Client_1 | 2/1/2021 | Store_2 | 2 |
| Client_2 | 2/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |
| Client_1 | 3/1/2021 | Store_1 | 2 |
| Client_2 | 3/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |

Where I would be actively counting the number of distinct stores a client visits over time. I've tried:

```
SELECT Client_ID, Appointment_Date, Store_ID,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID, STORE_ID ORDER BY APPOINTMENT_DATE)
FROM table
```

Which yields:

| Customer_ID | Appointment_Date | Store_ID | Count_Different_Stores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client_1 | 1/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |
| Client_2 | 1/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |
| Client_1 | 2/1/2021 | Store_2 | 2 |
| Client_2 | 2/1/2021 | Store_1 | 2 |
| Client_1 | 3/1/2021 | Store_1 | 3 |
| Client_2 | 3/1/2021 | Store_1 | 3 |

And:

```
SELECT Client_ID, Store_ID,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_ID, STORE_ID)
FROM table
--With a join back to the original table with all my needed data
```

Which yields:

| Customer_ID | Appointment_Date | Store_ID | Count_Different_Stores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Client_1 | 1/1/2021 | Store_1 | 2 |
| Client_2 | 1/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |
| Client_1 | 2/1/2021 | Store_2 | 1 |
| Client_2 | 2/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |
| Client_1 | 3/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |
| Client_2 | 3/1/2021 | Store_1 | 1 |

The second one is closer to what I need, but the ranking of the distinct stores doesn't necessarily account for the order of `Appointment_Date`, which is critical. Sometimes the order will be correct, and sometimes not.

Any insight is helpful, happy to provide more information.

Comment: I'm lost.  You are starting with four rows.  Where do the additional rows and dates come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a cumulative `count(distinct)` as a window function.  Snowflake does not support that directly, but you can easily calculate it using `row_number()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum( (seqnum = 1)::int) over (partition by client_id order by appointment_date) as num_distinct_stores
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by client_id, store_id order by appointment_date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. If I'm understanding, this gets the `ROW_NUMBER()` for each unique Client_ID / Store_ID combination as `seqnum`, and then with that in the subquery, each distinct `seqnum` is cast as a 1 and added into the total.

Comment: @VBAmazing . . . `ROW_NUMBER()` enumerates the rows for each client/store in order based on the date.  Then, only the first time (i.e. `= 1`) is counted.